# 8 Puzzle, graph tree paths generator

Tags: php, javascript, algorithm, puzzle

I'm looking for 8 Puzzle graphs tree generator, preferable in (php+) html+css+javascript. What i need is something like

```
3 2 1
6   8
7 5 4
```

will generate all the possible tree, like

```
3   1     3 2 1
6 2 8       6 8
7 5 4     7 5 4
```

and so on, until meet its goal.

Any link or algorithm is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.8puzzle.com/8_puzzle_algorithm.html for the explanation of the algoritm.

Creating such an efficient application is time-consuming, and requires skills in mathematics (field theory) and JS/PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you lack the mathematical background you can define a set of successor states from a certain state. Then throw all that into a search tree and add a little Zobrist hashing to avoid cycles.